# ExpressJS: Where to add bodyParser for middleware?

Tags: javascript, express, graphql

This is how I'm using bodyParser as middleware for my expressJS/graphQL server.

```
const graphqlMiddleware = [
  // bodyParser is needed just for POST.
  bodyParser.json(),
  bodyParser.text({ type: 'application/graphql' }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With')
    if (req.is('application/graphql')) {
      req.body = { query: req.body }
    }
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.sendStatus(200)
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
]

app.use('/graphql',
  ...graphqlMiddleware,
  graphqlExpress(req => ({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: { db: req.app.locals.db }
  }))
)
```

Now I tried to restructure my files, so I moved the function to

**/middlewares/graphql.js**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With')
  if (req.is('application/graphql')) {
    req.body = { query: req.body }
  }
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.sendStatus(200)
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

...and import it in my entrypoint:

**app.js**

```
import graphqlMiddleware from './middlewares/graphql'

app.use('/graphql',
  graphqlMiddleware,
  graphqlExpress(req => ({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: { db: req.app.locals.db }
  }))
)
```

But how (and where) should I add the bodyParser?

```
bodyParser.json(),
bodyParser.text({ type: 'application/graphql' })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/graphql',
  bodyParser.text({ type: 'application/graphql' }),
  graphqlMiddleware,
  graphqlExpress(req => ({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: { db: req.app.locals.db }
  }))
)
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't `bodyParser.json()` also only be added to `graphql`?

Comment: you can add it only to `/graphql`, but you will likely need it in others endpoints of the application so you can put it at the top like that